# does any template engine like Freemarker support customized constraints?

Tags: constraints, freemarker

I want to use template to render my output, just like Freemarker does, but I want to add customized constraints, for example, ${name}[length > 4 && notEmpty], ${name} is a variable, expression in [] is customized expression, "length > 4" means ${name}.legnth is greater than 4, "notEmpty" means ${name} is not null nor "", if these constraints do not return true, template engine can stop rendering with throwing an exception or do something else. Every variable in template may have its own constraints, and I don't want to write too many [#if][/#if] tags(it seems that Freemarker does not support stopping rendering if [#if] returns false). I just search Freemarker, it doesn't support, do you know any other template engine can meet my demand?

thanks.

Comment: Actually, FreeMarker can stop rendering with `<#stop>`, or with your custom directive that throws an exception.

Comment: @ddekany, yes, you are right, I didn't read Freemarker manual carefully, thanks.